# spark Listner OnApplicationEnd event stops only Driver, executors are not getting cleaned up

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I like to use sparklistner to end application execution, while I stop the application, it only stops the driver and it did not clean or stop the Executors.

whatever the Executors Added when I start the application using onApplicationStart Spark Listner should end both Driver and Executors, when I invoke a method onApplicaitonEnd, but actually it only terminates the driver and not the Executors

```
class testListner extends SparkListner {
    override def onApplicationEnd(appEnded:SparkListnerApplicationEnd):Unit ={}
}
object slyest extends App {sc.addSparkListner(new testListner)}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *not clean or stop the Executors*.

Comment: I mean executors should stop when my application calls this onApplicationEnd Spark Listner method, this method is stoping only the driver and I still see the executors are on and running. I am looking for a solution which can end these executors which where previously added by Spark Listner onApplicationStart Method